Salesforce CLI installation issue using NPM
I do not have admin access so I am forced to install Salesforce CLI using NPM.
NodeJS version - v20.14.0
openjdk version "22.0.1"
When I run nodeJs terminal, I can see there "@salesforce/cli/2.60.13 win32-x64 node-v20.14.0".  <---this feels like CLI has been installed, but it does not run using VS/Windows CMD.
When I run windows CMD or VS code and run "sf --version" I see the error "sf : The term 'sf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again."
Please help? Do I need to add something in Path? I added JDK, Nodejs in paths but still no success.

